# Filter Dataframe from Twitter API to exclude non-English text in R

Tags: r, stringr, rtweet

I have a data frame containing tweets from the twitter API that has English and non-Engilsh tweets. Before posting this question, I have searched stack overflow and did not seem to find something that addresses what I am intending.

Since twitter has emojis, I want to filter out tweets that are not in English without consideration to emojis. I have tried using `stringi::stri_enc_isascii()` but that does not seem to recognize English tweets with Emojis as English.

For replication purposes, here are some texts:

```
"私は、トランプ大統領を信じています #America"
"Thank you Nashville"
" Bless America"
```

In the final corpus, I should only have the last two texts.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that you're a bit misguided here. It's not guaranteed that just because something is encoded as ASCII it is English. What about every other language that uses the latin alphabet?

Comment: What about tweets partially in English and partially in non-English? e.g. `"私は、Trump大統領を信じています"`

Comment: @Hong good point. If we go further, the only plausible solution would be using a machine learning model to determine whether or not a sentence is 100% English (+ emojis).

Comment: @Hong Thank you! No, in that case, that tweet would be deleted.

Comment: @Jennifer did my answer help you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all non-ASCII characters from your dataset by doing:

```
# assuming tweets is the field name where you store the tweets text messages
dataset$tweets <- sapply(dataset$tweets, function(x) gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", x))
```

Then all your emojis and non-ascii characters will be left blank. The next step would be selecting only the rows where the tweets field is not empty.

```
dataset <- dataset[dataset$tweets != ""]
```

Now, if you want to **keep** the emojis, a better solution is to just do this process for indexing purposes and then use the index to filter the untouched data. For example:

```
modified_tweets <- sapply(dataset$tweets, function(x) gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", x))

# now filter by condition
dataset <- dataset[modified_tweets != ""]
```